# Fastest way to loop and copy data from one DataSet to another DataSet

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataset

I have one DataSet that contain 2 relate DataTable (master and details). I want to copy data that match my filter (e.g. master data column A = "XXX") to another DataSet.

Now I found that this process take a very very long time (about one hour for 1k records).

I want to know how to improve this processing time?

Comment: This does not make sense. If you have a DataSet, that means it's in memory and with 1K records, even if you looped over and over and compared each row 10 times, it still would not take one hour. Show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say copy-ing 1000 records should only take a few milliseconds.
Make sure there are no events firing or databindings doing strange things..
Maybe you should try without the relations but I believe enforcecontraints=false also disable foreign key checking..

The following code copies a complete dataset quite fast:

```
fDstDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
foreach (DataTable fSrcTable in fSrcDataSet.Tables)
{
    DataTable fDstTable = fOpenOrders.Tables[fSrcTable.TableName];
    foreach (DataRow fSrcRow in fSrcTable.Rows)
    {
        fDstTable.ImportRow(fSrcRow);
    }
}
fDstDataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

Comment: EnforceConstraints on a DataSet like that is only the constraint of the in memory dataset, not back to the actual database constraints.  If you have a simple table filled from a DataAdapter there are usually no constraints present.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try;

```
 myDataSet.Tables[0].Select("A = 'xxx'");
```

Which returns `DataRow[]`

Answer (score 0):

You might gain some benefit in outlining your problem in greater detail - there may be a better option then duplicating your data.

If you really want to go down this path you may want to take a look at the DataView class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

This will allow you to extract data based on a filter from a datatable. The DataView also has a method ToTable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.totable.aspx

This will return a datatable, based on the selected rows in the DataView.

This should perform better then your version, although I am not sure if other options will provide faster implementations again. I believe the above DataTable.Select will perform better then the DataView